# Datastax DSE Solr Error

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

I have a CQL3 table with composite keys (id int, category text, property text).

When I publish the Solr Schema I get this error:

> Solr indexes are not supported on ColumnFamilies with non-string comparators

Has anyone faced the same issue, or know how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DSE Solr does not support Composite Keys.

Unsupported features
DSE Search does not support:

- Cassandra super columns
- Cassandra counter columns
- Cassandra timeseries type rows
- **Cassandra composite columns**, Solr fields must be strings.

[DSE Solr Source](http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.1/solutions/dse_search_getting_started)

Answer (score 0):

What release of DSE are you using? CQL3 support for Solr was added in 3.2, but not fully supported before that release.